# How to properly manage an IAsyncEnumerable that returns IDisposables

Tags: c#, idisposable, iasyncenumerable

I have `IAsyncEnumerable<Segment> RetrieveSegments()` where `Segment : IDisposable`.

My question is how to properly manage this such that the `Segments` get disposed at the end of each iteration.

The current solution I have is this:

```
await foreach (var segment in RetrieveSegments())
{
    try 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        segment?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is this good enough, there is no `await foreach (using var segment in RetrieveSegments())`.

Or is there perhaps some better way to avoid this all together, the `Segment` is `IDisposable` because within it it holds a `Stream`.

I would like your opinions on this, as I think my current solution can lead to things not being disposed if used improperly.

Comment: What you have looks fine to me

Comment: You can do `using (segment) { }` inside the loop.

Comment: perhaps the `RetrieveSegments` should be managing the disposal, depending on whether `segment` is not expected to be stored and used outside the loop?

Comment: That is a fair point, I've just done some testing to ensure the segments are disposed of at the correct time and it does actually work. Thank you